# Prove the inequality $n(a-1) \sqrt{a^{n-1}}+1\le a^n$ for all $a \ge 1$ and $n \in N$.

Tags: inequality

Prove the inequality $n(a-1) \sqrt{a^{n-1}}+1\le a^n$ for all $a \ge 1$ and $n \in N$.

**My work**. I proved this inequality by investigate function using the derivative. But I would like to know an elementary proof without derivatives. This inequality can also be written as $\sqrt{a^{n+1}}-\sqrt{a^{n-1}}\le \frac{a^n-1}{n}$. And I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Induction on $n$ seems worthwhile to check..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be proved with the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality): for nonnegative real numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ we have
$$
(x_1\times\cdots\times x_n)^{1/n}\le\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\cdot
$$

Apply the latter with $x_k=a^{k-1}$ and you get
$$
(1\times a\times a^2\times\cdots\times a^{n-1})^{1/n}=\frac{1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}}{n}\cdot
$$

The left-hand side is equal to $(a^{n(n-1)/2})^{1/n}=a^{(n-1)/2}$. The right-hand side, assuming that $a\neq1$, is equal to $\frac{a^n-1}{n(a-1)}$. If $a>1$ or equivalently $a-1>0$ then we deduce that
$$
n(a-1)a^{(n-1)/2}+1\le a^n.
$$

Of course this inequality is satisfied for $a=1$, for which it is even an equality.

This method actually allows us to derive more information:

- As the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means is an equality if and only if $x_1=\cdots=x_n$, we deduce that the inequality $n(a-1)a^{(n-1)/2}+1\le a^n$ is strict for $a>1$.
- If $0<a<1$ we deduce in the same way that $n(a-1)a^{(n-1)/2}+1>a^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can prove your re-written inequality $ \sqrt{ a^{n+1} } - \sqrt{ a^{n-1}} \leq \frac{ a^n - 1 } { n } $ using AM-GM.
In fact, it is already in that form, so you just need to find suitable variables.

> Use $b_i = a^ i - a^{i-1}$.

Their arithmetic mean is $ \frac{ a^n-1 } { n}$, which is the RHS.
Their geometric mean is $ \sqrt[n] { a^{\frac{(n-1)n}{2}} (a-1)^n} = a^\frac{n-1}{2} ( a- 1) = \sqrt{a^{n+1} } - \sqrt{ a^{n-1}}$, which is the LHS.

Equality holds iff $b_i$ are equal, which means $ a = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!